# Header section in the uicollectionview controller. out of range

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview

I am using the `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` function to apply the header section from the `uicollectionview` controller. However, before the asynchronous parsing of the `viewDidAppear` API, the row index is loaded into the `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` function and becomes out of range. What should I do?

Here is my code...

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        callVideo3API()
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

        switch kind {

        case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:
            let row1 = self.list[0]
            let row2 = self.list[1]
            let row3 = self.list[2]

    let headerSection = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "Header", for: indexPath) as! HeaderSection


        headerSection.nameLabel01.text = row1.nickname
        headerSection.nameLabel02.text = row2.nickname
        headerSection.nameLabel03.text = row3.nickname


        return headerSection

    default:

        assert(false, "Unexpected element kind")
    }
}
```

Comment: it came because of the data source may be empty. So, you must have to reload `collectionView` after getting data source . and also post your `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView` and `numberOfItemsInSection` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must wait until the `callVideo3API()` get completed. After successful completion of `callVideo3API()` you can reload the collection view to get the output. Please follow below steps

1. Call method `callVideo3API()`
2. Make `CollectionView` empty by returning zero through ***CollectionView
   DataSource*** **[**`func numberOfSections(in collectionView:
   UICollectionView)  -> Int`, `func collectionView(_ collectionView:
   UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int` ***]***
3. ***(Optional)*** On the time of `callVideo3API()` execution you can a show an activity indicator on place of your CollectionView
4. After successful completion of `callVideo3API()` you can reload
   `CollectionView` with corresponding DataSource Value. This time it
   will work without any fault :-) *(If you put activity indicator don't forget to remove after successful api call)*